# How to use the encode with multiple email addresses and with subject line

Tags: expressionengine

I'm new to Expression Engine and trying to use the {encode} for two email addresses and would also like to pass a Subject line to the email when the user clicks on the link.

I was looking at the user guide for the encode standard global variable:

```
{encode="you@example.com" title="Email Me!"}
```

Could someone please provide an example of how to use the encode to include two email addresses as well as pass a Subject line?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass more than one email addresses to the EE email encode function, nor set the subject line.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you then perhaps let me know how I could use the encode function like a mailto call as I would like to also pass the subject to the email? If not encode, how else could I perform a mailto call within EE? Thanks.

Comment: Just with the usual HTML syntax should work: `<a href="mailto:someone@url.com?subject=A very important email">Send an email</a>`. The support for that "subject" syntax will be limited by email client though.